# Return multiple results in OpenRefine using Python / Jython RegEx

Tags: python, regex, jython, data-cleaning, openrefine

So, I'm trying to extract a few dates displayed as *dd.mm.yyyy*.

Some of the cells contain only one date, some of them contain multiple dates (like from *dd.mm.yyyy* to *dd.mm.yyyy*), along with more texts I don't care about.

I would need to extract both dates in order to create two columns - "From" and "To", leaving blanks for the ones with the events which happened on only one date.

I've tried using the following expression in Python / Jython, but it only returns the first dates for the cells which contain more than one.

```
import re
g = re.search("([0-9])([0-9])\.([0-9])([0-9])\.([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])", value)
return g.group()
```

How can I have both of the dates returned?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.findall()` to get all matches. Also make your regex a bit simpler by removing capturing groups for each digits and using `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

```
import re
g = re.findall("\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}", value)
return g
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked in the preview, but when I try to transform the cells or to add a new column based on that, it returns nothing on the dataset

Comment: Just realized I should specify which member of the list g I wanted on my cells. It worked! Thank you once more :)